# CakePHP Pagination problem with binding models

Tags: php, html, css, cakephp

Im using a Model `Post`. it doesn't have any associations. but for a paginated action i need to display the user name also, so used `$this->Post->bindModel()` to attach `User` model to the Posts. But i'm not getting the Users attached with the Post in the resulting query. The problem i think is the `paginate` method initially makes a call like `find('count')` to get the total no of results, so the bind is removed from there on. Have a look at my `paginate` variable

```
var $paginate = array(
        'limit'=>10,
        'order'=>'created DESC'
    );
```

In the action

```
$this->Post->bindModel(array(
            'belongsTo'=>array(
                'User'=>array(
                    'className'=>'User',
                    'fields'=>'User.username,User.id',
                    'foreignKey'=>'user_id'
                )
            )
        ));

$this->paginate('Post');
```

Answer (score 6):

If you use bindModel, after a call to a find method, the model gets unbinded.

You need to add a boolean false, like this: bindModel(array(...),false).

This way it will still be binded after the paginateCount call ...

Answer (score 0):

the fields should be 'fields'=>array(..). But I think you shouldn't specify that.